# Interaction between javaScript and python in eclipse

Tags: javascript, python, eclipse

I am new in eclipse and python, I want to call methods of python from java Script.Is it correct to use ajax? if yes how is the syntax and what should I do to my python module for make them accessible  from java script?
thank you so much

Comment: What does this have to do with Eclipse? That's an IDE for writing code, it has nothing to do with making Ajax requests or serving a website with Python.

Comment: To run Python from JavaScript you need AJAX (it is method in JavaScript to send HTTP request to web server and receive HTTP response). And you need Web Server which receives HTTP request from JavaScript, executes Python code and sends result to JavaScript as HTTP response. You can use Python Web Framework like `flask`, `bottle`, `django`, etc.